# Displaying Json table in HTML Table

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, json, django

I have some JSON data that is returned by a Django web app that I want to display within a HTML List. For some reason, it's not working for me. The JSON is generated by a Ajax Get request which displays all the products in the database. The get request works as is supposed to but when I try to display the details of the products to the Html page, nothing is shown. Here is the relevant code I have so far: 
This is the Views.py file:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
from products.models import Product
from django.http import HttpResponse, JsonResponse

def index(request):
    return render(request, 'index.html')


def viewProduct(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        product_list = Product.objects.all()
        products=[]
        for prod in product_list:
            products.append({"name": prod.name, "description": prod.description, "price": prod.price})
    return JsonResponse(products, safe=False)
```

The Index.html page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
  <div>
  <h2 id="title">Create product</h2>
  <input id="name">Name</input>
  <br>
  <input id="description">Description</input>
  <br>
  <input id="price">Price</input>
  <br>
  <button id="add-product">ADD PRODUCT</button>
  </div>

  <table id = "employee-table">
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Description</th>
      <th>Price</th>
    </tr>    
  </table>
</body>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

  document.getElementById('add-product').onclick =  function(){
    sendData();
    getData();
  }

function getData(){
  $.ajax({
    url: 'view/product',
    dataType: 'json',
    type: 'GET',
    success: function(data){
      console.log("success")
      var dmJSON = "http://localhost:8000/view/product";
      $.getJSON(dmJSON, function(data) {
        $.each(data.entries, function(i, f) {
          var tblRow = "<tr>" + "<td>" + f.name + "</td>" + "<td>" + f.description + "</td>" + "<td>" + f.price + "</td>" + "</tr>"
          $(tblRow).appendTo("#employee-table");
      });
    })
  }})
}

</script>
</html>
```

The Json is present when I go to the URl "http://localhost:8000/view/product" and comes in the format:

```
[{
        "name": "iPhone",
        "description": "Apple iPhone",
        "price": "200"
    }, {
        "name": "Samsung Galaxy",
        "description": "Samsung Phone",
        "price": "150"
    }
```

What I want to do is to loop through all these products and display them to a table. This dosen't work though so I'm not sure what to do from here. I have checked the getData() method in the index.html page and it does output the console.log message within the success function. The only part that does not work is the displaying of the items within the table. Thanks in advnce for any help.

Comment: There is no property `entries` in the response object shown which is an array. Should just be `$.each(data, func...`

Comment: thank you so much, fixed my issue for me.